How can I extend a discriminated union type using a generic type parameter?
I have a library which follows the typescript idiom of defining a type as a union of object types.  Each of the objects has a type field with a different discriminator value.  Lets say it is defined as
type Core = { type: 'core-1' } | { type: 'core-2' }

Code that uses the library can add its own object types to the union.  I'm trying to model the most general way in which this could happen by defining a type AnyTypedObject which is intended to mean any object type that has a string valued type field.  So we say
type AnyTypedObject = { type: string; } & { [key: string]: any; }

I'd like to say that the type field cannot be one of the values used in the library, but my understanding is that this cannot be done through typescript.
Within the library I want to define generic functions which are aware of the possibility that the object type has extra fields.  They take a generic type parameter B to specify the extension.  E.g we could write
type TypedObject<B extends AnyTypedObject> = B | Core
type Types<B extends AnyTypedObject> = TypedObject<B>['type']

The intent is that Types<B> is a union of all of the potential object types, both the objects from Core or those in the extension B.
I can then use Types<B> in other definitions.  For example we could define an object type which only has the discriminator field and nothing else.
type PureType<B extends AnyTypedObject, K extends Types<B> = Types<B>> = { type: K; }

Now I want to define a function that takes as input a pure type object.  Here we are just returning the input to illustrate the problem.
function foo<B extends AnyTypedObject, K extends Types<B> = Types<B>>(
    input: PureType<B, K>,
) {
    return input;
}

The issue is that typescript is giving me an error with this function definition.  It states that

Type 'K' does not satisfy the constraint 'Types'.
Type 'Types' is not assignable to type 'never'.
Type '"core-1"' is not assignable to type 'never'

Once I provide an explicit value for B it works as expected.  We can do the following:
type Extension = { type: 'extension' } | { type: 'other' };
foo<Extension>({ type: 'core-1' });       // okay
foo<Extension>({ type: 'core-2' });       // okay
foo<Extension>({ type: 'extension' });    // okay
foo<Extension>({ type: 'other' });        // okay
foo<Extension>({ type: 'invalid' });      // fails as intended

I experimented with changing the definition of Core.  If it contains an empty union then there is no error.  If it contains exactly one object type then the error message changes.  It looks like TS is inferring that K must be the intersection of all the discriminator values instead of the union.  So as soon as two explicit values are available it infers that K must be never.
My question:
Why does TS reject the definition of foo()?  I know that the example shown here does not make much sense - I cut it down from a much larger project.
TS Playground containing all code from this question

Please [edit] this to ask a single primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

Assuming you decide that you are really asking question #1, I've filed https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/60892 and will wait to see what they say

Your implementation seems overkill.
If you remove PureType and Types, you can succeed in getting out of this without error. Is this fitting your need ?
type Core = { type: "core-1" } | { type: "core-2" };

type AnyTypedObject = { type: string } | { [key: string]: any };

type TypedObject<B extends AnyTypedObject> = B | Core;

function foo<B extends AnyTypedObject>(input: TypedObject<B>) {
  return input;
}

foo<{ url: "/about" }>({ url: "/about" }); // okay
foo<{ url: "/about" }>({ url: "okok" }); // fails as intended
foo<{ url: "/about" }>({ uri: "/about" }); // fails as intended

EDIT: On the other hand, a better answer to your enquiry would be this. Recognise that defining type: "core-1 is actually defining a value, whereas K (generic types) are of type never. Consequently, extending a typed value to a type never would not work, only the contrary can (extending a type never to a typed value). Following code raise no error:
type PureType<K> = {
  type: K;
};

function foo<B extends AnyTypedObject, K extends Types<B> = Types<B>>(
  input: PureType<K>
) {
  return input;
}


Thank you for your response.  I agree that the example I used does not make much sense.  But I cut it down from more complex types trying to get simplest example of case where I'm seeing an error.  In my code I want a function that accepts a patch of a valid object type (i.e. it always has discriminator field and then it has a subset of other fields).  I get a similar error to the one shown here.  But I don't understand why TS rejects the code I'm writing here.
